# selenium webdriver hang in very simple javascript code with promise.then

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, promise, event-loop

I had experienced a very strange bug with nodejs & selenium-webdriver recently. It looks related with nodejs event loop / promise / selenium-webdriver.

In short: **webdriver.get call will hang when use with some `promise.then`.**

## First, let's see a piece of javascript code which works well:

```
const WebDriver     = require('selenium-webdriver')

var driver = new WebDriver.Builder()
.setAlertBehavior('ignore')
.forBrowser('chrome')
.build()

function ok() {
  console.log('ok: driver.get will open a browser window\n' + '\n' + ok + '\n')
  driver.get('about:blank')
}

ok()
```

This code will open a browser window, which works as expected.

But all of the following code will show strange behaviour.

## Bug - driver.get will hang

after add a dummy `.then(() => 'test')`

```
function bug() {
  console.log('bug: `driver.get` will hang\n' + '\n' + bug + '\n')
  Promise.resolve()
  .then(() => 'test')
  .then(() => driver.get('about:blank'))
}
```

## Fix1 - delete the 1st `then` call

```
function fire1() {
  console.log('fix1: delete the `then` call\n' + '\n' + fire1 + '\n')
  Promise.resolve()
  .then(() => driver.get('about:blank'))
}
```

## Fix2 - or add a `catch` call

```
function fire2() {
  console.log('fix2: add a `catch` call\n' + '\n' + fire2 + '\n')
  Promise.resolve()
  .then(() => 'test')
  .catch(e => console.error(e))
  .then(() => driver.get('about:blank'))
}
```

## Fix3 - or resolve the promise with a `setTimeout` instead of resolve directly

```
function fire3() {
  console.log('fix3: resolve promise with a `setTimeout` call\n' + '\n' + fire3 + '\n')
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 0)
  })
  .then(() => 'test')
  .then(() => driver.get('about:blank'))
}
```

All of the above code is tested under nodejs v6.0.0.

Has there anybody met this kind of problem before? What's the reason behind this?

I thought it maybe related with the nodejs event loop, or native promise implementation... but I'm dont know how to deep any more.

Code in Gist: https://gist.github.com/zixia/77896cbd446c7282f760c60a025fee17

Github issue: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2233

Comment: Very strange. Starting with your "Bug - driver.get will hang" version, would `.then(function() { return 'test'; })` fix it?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 no. .then(...) is the reason cause the bug. if you get rid of `.then(...)`, it will work as expected. if you add a `.catch(...)` to pair with the `.then(...)`, it will work as expected too. very strange.

Comment: It seems like success depends on the number of microtasks between `driver = new WebDriver.Builder()....build()` and `driver.get('about:blank')`. Zero, 1 and 3 microtasks ahead are all ok, but 2 is not. But why would that matter?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 yes, you got it. Did you re-produced the problem using my demo code?

Comment: No, I've not tried to reproduce the problem. I've just inspected the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a confirmed webdriver bug with non-native promise code.

after upgrade to native promise code, this bug finally disapears.

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2233#issuecomment-225445538